# Element overgrowing it's child

Tags: css

I have an element inside a parent that have a `flex-grow` of `1`.

How to prevent that element from overgrowing that parent?

```
<div style="flex-grow:1">
    <overgrowingChild>....<overgrowingChild/>
<div/>
```

Answer (score 1):

add to the parent  : `overflow : hidden`